# Laravel 8 dev project with Laravel Sail and versioning

Tags: git, windows-subsystem-for-linux, laravel-8, laravel-sail

I'm learning Laravel 8, and I want to set up a quick dev environment using Laravel Sail.

Since we usually don't commit to the vendor directory in Git, how can we run Sail from a fresh Git clone? We can't use "composer install" without it. Does it mean we should commit the vendor/bin and vendor/composer folders? What are the common practices about it?

Should we commit /vendor/bin to git for a fresh dev environment out of the box?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I have stumbled across the exact same problem.
In the documentation there is the following section solving that:

> You may install the application's dependencies by navigating to the application's directory and executing the following command. This command uses a small Docker container containing PHP and Composer to install the application's dependencies:

```
docker run --rm \
    -u "$(id -u):$(id -g)" \
    -v $(pwd):/var/www/html \
    -w /var/www/html \
    laravelsail/php81-composer:latest \
    composer install --ignore-platform-reqs
```

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/sail#installing-composer-dependencies-for-existing-projects

Of course you also have to prepare the .env-File and other not commited dependencies.

Comment: Could you please explain what exactly do I have to prepare? I tried to run this command but it gives error. There's no information about it anywhere. Thank you in advance

Comment: If you use docker, you can run the docker run command mentioned above (from the doc link) to have composer in your virtual machine. Then you can :
"composer require laravel/sail --dev"
"php artisan sail:install"
"./vendor/bin/sail up"
And then you sail is available

Comment: I got error too when execute in powershell